# change image in another when click on a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I would like to know if there is a way of changeing an image with another when clicking on a button. I have 6 images with correct feedback and i must change them in wrong feedback when i click on a button. Image to change in html is  with

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/usPMd/107/

```
var btn =   $('#btn');
var idd = $('#idd');

btn.click(function() {  
   idd.toggle(800, function() {

        btn.attr('src', 'images/wrong.svg'); 
              }
    });
  });
```

Comment: The images in your fiddle are broken. Please provide a working link and tell us what exactly is not working. The code you provided seems fine.

Comment: Your brackets are also off. You need to close the ")" of the toggle call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you're after with the toggle function, but it works once your syntax is fixed:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/Ma4N9

```
var btn = $('.boxImg');
var idd = $(btn).next('p').find('.feedback');

btn.click(function () {
    idd.toggle(800, function () {
        btn.attr('src', 'http://placekitten.com/300/300');
    });
});
```

Comment: ure changeing different images..i need to change only images with class feedback into another image which is external

Comment: Simplify your fiddle, clarify your question, and include a sample of relevant HTML.

Comment: i did it : $(document).ready(function () {
    
            $("#validateButton").click(function () {
                $(".feedback").show();
                $('.feedback').attr('src', 'res/wrong.svg');
            });
           
        });

Comment: untill click this image is hidden,after click its shown and changed.But now i must make submit function for 6 input fields and i need to include this function to be called if there are wrong answers,otherlese just show the first image (without change it)

Comment: Please don't post code and explanations in comments. Put it up in your question where it's readable and does some good.

Comment: sorry,im new here but from now on i know what to do